# Unable to install JDK - malformed configuration file

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration-files

I have thouroughly scoured the internet for anyone who has encountered the same error as me but to no success. I also checked this website for any previous threads asking a similar question and found nothing helpful.

I want to install a Java Development Kit (JDK) which I need to do in order to program a mod for Minecraft. I've downloaded: 'jdk-8u5-windows-x64' from the official Oracle website as I was instructed to by a person's tutorial. The guy said that installing the JDK is "pretty straight-forward" and that all you have to do is "download the executable and run it, and it will install everything for you".

**Here's the problem/error.** When I open the exe. for the JDK installer I get the following error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exqxj.png

And when I go to the directory I see this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sSB0.png

*Notes that may be of interest:*

1. I have previously installed and uninstalled versions of Java in the past.
2. I'm using this JDK for the program 'Eclipse' which I have recently re-installed.
3. I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: You'd better cleanup your previously installed jDK. so thereis shouldn't be any folders like that.

Comment: make sure you have a 64-bit OS for that jdk you downloaded. Also try to uninstall if you installed the same version before.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all very much, it's fixed now. I found a folder with a previous version of JDK that I had installed in the past and deleted that. I then navigated to the directory that it gave and deleted the configuration file it was complaining about.

Comment: Thank you! That also worked for me. I'd just like to add that I had to give full access rights to this folder so I could complete the installation.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the file allows it to be regenerated but the error is telling you the actual issue.

If you look at line 1 in your java.settings.cfg, you will see that it doesn't match the Oracle flags. How this happens I don't know but I noticed it installing Java 9 JDK on a new machine.

On an installation of java 8, I had the settings line 1 as "AUTOUPDATE=0" 
But if you check the [config guidelines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/config.html).
You will see the actual pair should have 'AUTO_UPDATE not AUTOUPDATE'.

You can delete the file but you are deleting your configuration and hoping it rebuilds correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue... I went to that directory it is complaining about in your screenshot.. and I deleted that file.  After that, the installer worked.  The directory won't show up -- so you have to type it to navigate to it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exqxj.png